# Registration form bringing back login credentials

Tags: php, forms, pdo

I have made a user registration form in PHP and when I access the page the username part of the form is already filled in as my own log in credentials and the same with the password.  The other parts of the form are filled in as an undefined index also.

Below shows the form and PHP code for my registration form.  The form itself actually works and populates to my database.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Ballymena Sports</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="home2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ballymena Sports</a>
  </div>
  
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></li>
  </ul>
  
   </div>
    </nav>
 
<?php
include"config.php"; 

 if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
  
  $username=$_POST['username'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $forename=$_POST['forename'];
  $surname=$_POST['surname'];
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $telephone=$_POST['telephone'];
  $address1=$_POST['address1'];
  $town=$_POST['town'];
  $postcode=$_POST['postcode'];
  
  $q = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?");
  $query = $q-> execute(array($username));
  $count = $q->rowCount();
  
  if($count == 0) {
   
   $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user SET username = ?, password = ?, forename = ?, surname = ?, email = ?, telephone = ?, address1 = ?, town=?, postcode=? ");
   $query = $query->execute(array($username,$password,$forename,$surname,$email,$telephone,$address1,$town,$postcode));
   
   if($query){
    echo "User successfully registered";
    header("Location:home2_template.html");   
    return; 
   } else {
    echo "Fail";
   }
  } else {
   echo "User already exists"; 
  }
  
 }
?>
<!-- Main part of homepage -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
  <div id="registerBody">
   <h2>Register your account</h2>
    <p>All fields within the registration form must be filled in</p>
  </div>
 <div class = "register">
  <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" action="">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" value="<?php echo $username ?>"required="required">
    </div> 
   </div>
    
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password ?>"required="required">
    </div>
   </div>
    
   <div class="form-group"> 
    <label for="forename" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Forename:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="forename" name="forename" value="<?php echo $forename ?>"required="required">
    </div>
   </div>
    
   <div class="form-group"> 
    <label for="surname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Surname:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" name="surname" value="<?php echo $surname ?>"required="required">
    </div>
   </div>
    
   <div class="form-group"> 
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <input type="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Match email format of 'email@provider.com'" value="<?php echo $email ?>"required="required">
    </div>
   </div>
    
   <div class="form-group"> 
    <label for="telephone" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Telephone:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{11}" class="form-control" id="telephone" name="telephone" placeholder="Match telephone format of 11 digits" value="<?php echo $telephone ?>"required="required">
    </div>
   </div>
    
   <div class="form-group"> 
    <label for="address1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address1" name="address1" value="<?php echo $address1 ?>"required="required">
    </div>
   </div>
    
   <div class="form-group"> 
    <label for="town" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Town:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="town" name="town" value="<?php echo $town ?>"required="required">
    </div>
   </div>
    
   <div class="form-group"> 
    <label for="postcode" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Postcode:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <input type="text" pattern ="[A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9Rr][0-9A-Za-z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Zabd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2}" class="form-control" id="postcode" name="postcode" placeholder="Match postcode format of 'XX00 0XX' "value="<?php echo $postcode ?>"required="required">
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input id="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary">
   </div> 
   </div> <!-- registration button --> 
  
  </form>
 </div> <!-- registration end --> 
  
 </div> <!-- container end -->
 </div> <!-- jumbo end -->
 
 <br>
 <!--<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input id="submit" name="reg" type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary">
  </div> 
 </div> -->

    <!-- end of reg -->  



    <div class="container">
  <br>
      <footer>
        <p>&copy; Ballymena Sports 2014</p>
      </footer>
    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Cheers 
Stuart

Comment: remove value="" from every field

Comment: Hi Vicky.  I want to have those values in so if they make a mistake on the form submission they don't have to fill all the values in again

Comment: if you saved password in browser for that website also it may show, in that case you must use jquery or javascript to remove the value

in jquery :
$("#idOfInput").val("");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Initialize all the variables with an empty string. You problem will be
>   resolved.

```
<?php    
$username="";
    $password="";
    $forename="";
    $surname="";
    $email="";
    $telephone="";
    $address1="";
    $town="";
    $postcode="";
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $forename=$_POST['forename'];
        $surname=$_POST['surname'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $telephone=$_POST['telephone'];
............
..........
......

..}
```